# how to show that $f(x)$ can be expressed uniquely as follows: $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k[f_i(x)]^{n_i}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(x)\in F[x],~F$ being a field, be monic. Then how to show that $f(x)$ can be expressed uniquely as follows:

$$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k[f_i(x)]^{n_i}$$

for some monic irreducible polynomial $f_i(x)\in F[x]$ and $k\in \mathbb N~(n_i$'s are positive integers)

Comment: What have you tried or thought about? Also, this fact (that for any field $F$, the ring $F[x]$ is a UFD) is in essentially any abstract algebra book .

Comment: More generally: If $R$ is a UFD, then so is $R[x]$. For a field, we even have that $F[x]$ is a principle ideal domain. Ofcourse you have uniqueness only if you demand $f_i\ne f_j$ for $i\ne j$.

Comment: @Sriti if $F$ is a field, then the polynomial ring $F[X]$ is an euclidean domain, hence in particular a UFD, meaning that for every $f(X)$ you have a unique factorization in product of powers of irreducible polynomials

Comment: Where have you encountered this problem? In particular, rings with this property are very well-studied objects called UFDs (unique factorization domains), so I'm curious where you came across the question since you seem to be unaware of the terminology... (?)

Comment: @EricStucky: It came in course of studying primary decomposition theorem in linear algebra.

Comment: @Sriti: As others have said, this result fits most naturally into the setting of abstract algebra, so unless you are willing to do some heavy reading, a reasonable answer is "beyond the scope of this course". Which is not really true; if you are studying the primary decomposition theorem in this level of detail you could probably suffer through a proof of this statement at the lower level of abstraction. But I don't see any particularly good reason for you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F$ is a field, $F[X]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain (take an ideal $I\neq 0$ of $F[x]$ and a polynomial of minimal degree in it, then conclude by Euclide's algorithm). Since any PID is also a Unique Factorization Domain (a proof of this fact can be found in most of abstract algebra's book, such as in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I), you're done.